# Multiple schemas in Gmail

Tags: google-schemas

Is it possible to embed multiple GMail schemas in a single email? I'd like to provide users the ability to retry or cancel an action (the cancel operation would perform some cleaning stuff in the server app). However, if I try to embed more than one script, only the first one appears in the inbox (each script is correct and shows up properly when it is the only one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only one action is currently supported and if you include multiple actions, the first one will be used. The user experience for exposing multiple actions would be really different, so if/how to handle them is still being discussed.

Comment: Any progress on that? Looks like nice way to interact with user, and Gmail seems to stay behind other channels when implementing multiple choices. Maybe going to separate page solely to select one of two options is not that good idea. RSVP is a good example of how such choices could be handled, Review on the other hand allows user input, but none of them is that universal.